# Android Percentage layout not working in RTL support

Tags: android

Currently am developing an android app that support both English and Arabic language. I have used PERCENTAGE layout for designing and am also using RTL support to implement in Arabic language. But margin_start or margin_end did not work in PERCENTAGE layout. Is there any solution for RTL support with PERCENTAGE layout?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_en"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_heightPercent="7%"
    app:layout_marginStartPercent="1.5%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="0.5%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="25%" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/lang"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/lang_selector"
    app:layout_heightPercent="7%"
    app:layout_marginEndPercent="3.5%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="0.5%"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_widthPercent="10%"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topic"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lang"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#6E6031"
    app:layout_marginBottomPercent="2%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="2%" />

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topic"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="15sp"
    app:layout_heightPercent="65%"
    app:layout_marginStartPercent="6%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="86%" />
```

Comment: different layouts ... one default in "layout" and second in "layout-rtl" ? and margin_right/left instead margin_end

Comment: Perhaps you could post the "PERCENTAGE" layout code?

Comment: I think he is using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html but I agree with you that sample layout would be helpful